# Reality Check: Meteor Shower buried supermetal in the earth's crust, that is now being mined out

Tags: space, geology, mining

Centuries ago, a localized meteor shower deposited rare "supermetal" in the side of a mountain range. Due to the force of the impact, it created a pockmarked area with the metal at varied depths. In the present day, a nation has sprung up in this area, mining the pockmarked area for the supermetal to be used in weapons and armor.

How realistic is this, geologically/as far as the meteor shower idea?

Comment: Marvel Comics clearly thinks it’s plausible, because you’re describing their fictional country of Wakanda.

Comment: I like the answers you're getting, but something should be pointed out. Meteors can't hit the earth in a way that they burrow down in a narrow puncture to various depths. If they're slow enough not to burn things, they make small craters and reside at the bottom of the craters. If they're fast enough to get to a significant depth (oh, let's say 50 meters) then we're talking explosive force and the material would be strewn to some degree over a sizable area of the planet. If you're striving for "realistic," (I'm not a fan), set your expectations accordingly.

Comment: @JBH could the metal be buried "at varied depths" due to where it struck? If a meteor hits the side of a mountain, it might cause a shallow crater in the mountain's side, but then that could be further buried by a rockslide caused by the impact?

Comment: @Syndic A gentle enough impact that the meteor didn't have an explosive effect but strong enough to cause a landslide that would bury it? I won't say it can't happen - but those be mighty long odds. The basic problem here is that meteors are traveling at a whomping high speed. Gentle isn't in their nature.

Comment: Which part of that are you asking about? In reality, any of it might be open to question. In a built world, who could doubt anything you postulated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One magic search phrase you might find useful is [strewn field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strewn_field).

> The term strewn field indicates the area where meteorites from a single fall are dispersed.

For a real world example, consider the [Gibeon meteorite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibeon_(meteorite)), which seems to have produced quite a few tonnes of metal fragments spread over thousands of square kilometres, some of which were exploited by locals to produce objects like spearheads. Other strewn fields are much smaller, so you can pick the size you need.

You have more specific requirements though, and that's where the problems arise:

> Due to the force of the impact, it created a pockmarked area with the metal at varied depths

Maximum depth of a penetrator is limited. [Newton's approximation for impact depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_approximation_for_impact_depth) says that it is approximately proportional to the size of the impactor, and the ratio of the densities of the materials involved... that means a metal impactor on terrestrial rock isn't ever going to penetrate more than a few times its own length. If a really big impactor hits the ground though, the energy of the impact will tend to vaporise large quantities of it which limits how much will be deposited, and how deep, too.

A meteorite that was composite of metal fragments glommed together in some other rocky or icy matrix that struck the Earth at a (comparatively) low speed and at a low angle could disintegrate in the upper atmosphere. The smaller chunks of useful material will be slowed more by the atmosphere and so hit at a much more sedate pace... the slower the better, so as to survive the event (the [Hoba meteorite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoba_meteorite) is a single 66+ tonne chunk, and might have hit at ~300 m/s). That gives you lots of material, but what it *doesn't* do it to bury any of it at all deeply. If you want *that*, then you need some other geological process to bury it in sediment or volcanic outflows or whatever, and that sort of thing doesn't produce impact-pockmarking... craters are a sign of *loss* of nice big lumps of stuff!

A combination of the two things... a breakup of a larger object, followed by the impact of one or more massive chunks to produce some nice dramatic craters, and finally the smaller fragments that lost more speed as they descended sprinkling themselves over the crater field *might* give you something like you want. Certainly, you could handwave it in.

Answer (score 10):

[Meteoric iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteoric_iron) being used as ore source is a thing. In the past, before mining technology was sufficiently developed, it was the only way to source iron.

> Meteoric iron, sometimes meteoritic iron, is a native metal and early-universe protoplanetary-disk remnant found in meteorites and made from the elements iron and nickel, mainly in the form of the mineral phases kamacite and taenite. Meteoric iron makes up the bulk of iron meteorites but is also found in other meteorites. Apart from minor amounts of telluric iron, meteoric iron is the only naturally occurring native metal of the element iron (in metallic form rather than in an ore) on the Earth's surface.

> Before the advent of iron smelting, meteoric iron was the only source of iron metal apart from minor amounts of telluric iron. Meteoric iron was already used before the beginning of the Iron Age to make cultural objects, tools and weapons.

Therefore the idea is plausible.

Comment: Excellent thank you. I couldn't think of a reason that it wouldn't work, because I was aware of the use of meteoric iron, but I wanted to double check that the general parameters worked. (Worldbuilding stackexchange is a GREAT place to go if you need someone to potentially yell at you that your idea is stupid/unrealistic)

Comment: I concur that this is plausible within limits. The history of [Barringer Crator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_Crater) indicates a likely upper bound on the total usable material for any one impact, as large impactors have a serious tendency to vaporize the meteor due to the energy of impact. Daniel Barringer lost his fortune trying to find the mother lode of iron he expected to find from this impact. A more valuable ore would change the equation somewhat as lower grade ore would be economically viable. Still limits the total material available though.

Comment: Note that meteoric iron is *terrible-quality iron*. It's notable because it was available before people had invented ways to smelt iron from ore, but it's not remotely a supermetal even within the context of a bronze age society.

Comment: of note, [bog iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bog_iron) was also a pre-iron age, iron use method

Answer (score 4):

The Sudbury basin is the result of a meteor and is a large mining area. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudbury_Basin In this case, the minerals might be the result of magma interacting with the meteor basin.

Your idea is feasible.

Answer (score 2):

"Supermetal" being a very general idea, I can think of the [33_Polyhymnia](https://www.businessinsider.com/asteroid-so-dense-could-contain-never-before-seen-elements-2023-10) asteroid. The asteroid is too dense to be made entirely out of "ordinary" matter. It is said to be much denser than Osmium, the densest element known. Measurement errors may have occurred, and the main reason being the small size of the asteroid making it difficult to measure the gravitational impact on other celestial bodies. Scientists say that nevertheless this may be something new.

The idea hinges on the possibility that the periodic table of elements contains what is called the "[Island of stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability)". Scientists are not yet sure whether some elements in this "island" are stable, or their half-life is enough for them to remain detectable over a long period, comparable to Plutonium or Uranium. Supernova explosions are powerful enough to generate neutron stars, which are basically a ball of neutrons. Neutron star mergers are said to generate heavy elements too, by the process of nucleosynthesis. So, scientists speculate that if a ball of neutrons can be generated by a supernova explosion or a neutron star merger, then it is possible there is enough pressure to generate super-heavy elements in the so-called island of stability. Their atomic number may reach 164, they speculate.

Food for thought: Nucleosynthesis - Which type of elements are nucleosynthesized, and by which astrophysical process [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleosynthesis).